# Jenkins slave with specific port

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have a main Jenkins server, running on a linux VM, listening on `foo.com:9090/jenkins`.

I need to create a node, on a windows VM, that is inside the same network.

I tried to do it using JavaWebStart, but i could not configure it right.        I need a way to specify the `/jenkins` path.   `foo.com:9090` doesn't work, neither `foo.com`. And when i specify the correct address, `foo.com:9090/jenkins`, The JNLP File gives a input exception on `/Jenkins`.

I tried SSH, but could not get it to work on Windows either.

Is there any way to specify on `/Jenkins` when configuring the host?

[Jenkins Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVL05.png)

Comment: Can you show me your node configuration?

Comment: [image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Qcqaush3SzySoDUrMCRVRA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security` and add a `Fixed Port` for JNLP Agents.

Then configure a firewall rule for the fixed port in your `master` machine so it can allow connections.

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo ufw allow <FIXED_PORT>/tcp
```

Then try to launch your agent.

Comment: I Fixed a port on JNLP Config and configured it on the tunnel to field on the slave configuration and it worked. Thanks

Comment: How did you add a firewall rule for fixed port in master jenkins machine? Can you please explain the steps? Thank you.